# Word for "Trying Suddenly"

Tags: word-request

How can I say something like this:

> It was getting dark. They suddenly understood the danger they were going to face. They ...... trying.

Or

> After the incident, different agencies .... to offer a practical solution.

I don't want to use words like **started** or **began**. In our language, we have something like: **to fall into scrambling** or **put into trying** Or somehow become **like a boiling water to do sth**. Sorry if these don't make sense.

Comment: The word "rush" comes to mind. Also, I think this helps you a lot, "to make a rash decision" ... adj. The definition of rash is something done or said too fast. An example of rash used as an adjective is a rash decision, a decision made without any consideration of the consequences.

Comment: Scrambled would work well in the second sentence.

Comment: One meaning of [fall](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fall) is "to set about heartily or actively". Please explain why you don't want words like *start* but seem to want something to mean *start*.

Answer (score 1):

One way to say "quickly started" is "dove into", taken from "to dive". It suggests rapid and committed decisions and actions. In the given example "set themselves to" may be well received.

Some ways to say "quickly started to" are "raced to", "rushed to" or "scrambled to" (which is similar to an offered example idiom and might be preferred).

Answer (score 0):

[Frantically](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/frantically)

> done in a hurried way and in a state of excitement or confusion:
>   I've been working frantically all week to get it finished on time.
>   I got home to find Lara frantically searching for her keys.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but no.

Comment: Can you extend your examples to give verbose examples (fill in the ...'s)

Comment: For example: It was getting dark. They suddenly understood the danger they were going to face. They 'Trying Suddenly' trying. Would not make sense. Can you think of an example that would make sense, even if it is not the word(s) you are looking for

Comment: _After the incident, different agencies **fell into trying** to offer a practical solution_ OR  _It was getting dark. They suddenly understood the danger they were going to face. They **forced into** trying._

Comment: What about they **became trying**. BTW, I'm really sorry for my silly examples. It seems that I'm not able to find a similar equivalent example even

Answer (score 0):

For the first example, I would consider something like **found themselves**. Like so:

> *It was getting dark. They suddenly understood the danger they were going to face. They found themselves trying to escape...* (or whatever)

This works best when a situation (or awareness of a situation) suddenly comes to the forefront and one acts on it before they even realize it, figuratively speaking.

---

For the second example, [James P](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/42526/james-p) suggested **scrambled** in a comment above, which works well, IMO. Similarly, **hurried** or **rushed** makes sense.

Or a couple of different notions: **deigned**, **arose** and **managed**.

> *After the incident, different agencies **deigned** to offer a practical solution.*
>
> *...different agencies **arose** to offer a practical solution.*
>
> *...different agencies **managed** to offer a practical solution.*

All infer different meanings, so it depends on your ultimate intention.

Answer (score 0):

A little more context would help but here are some suggestions.

It was getting dark. They suddenly understood the danger they were going to face.

> They **put everything they had into** coming up with a solution to eliminate the danger.

> They **desperately started trying** to solve the problem and eliminate the danger.

> They **gave it their best shot** and came up with a way to avoid the danger.